# SQL Query Date conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in `Ms SQL Server` 2005 (2008) in following structure

```
ID Name     AddDate                   AmendDate                 Status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  Jason    2012-09-03 08:01:00.000   2012-09-03 14:02:00.000   Amended
2  Robert   2012-09-03 08:05:00.000   NULL                      New
3  Celia    2012-09-03 08:10:00.000   2012-09-03 14:02:00.000   Amended
4  Jason    2012-09-03 14:02:00.000   NULL                      New
5  Robert   2012-09-03 14:03:00.000   2012-09-03 20:02:00.000   Amended
6  Celia    2012-09-03 14:07:00.000   2012-09-03 20:02:00.000   Amended
7  Jason    2012-09-03 20:00:00.000   NULL                      New
8  Robert   2012-09-03 20:02:00.000   NULL                      New
9  Celia    2012-09-03 20:04:00.000   NULL                      New
```

routine runs three times per day as snapshot,

please how can I by using SQL Query

1. select all record from morning (or evening) for any of days
2. how can I replace (`ISNULL(AmendDate, '2012.09.04')`) for column `AmendDate` where is `Null value`, in the case when I walking in history, for example returns all row that `AddDate <= '2012-09-01' and AmendDate >= '2012-09-02'`
3. question is about `SELECT - FROM - WHERE -` only

Comment: what do you mean by "walking in history"? also, do you want to consider null AmendDate as 2012.09.04?

Comment: @Vikdor `"walking in history"` I meaning resultset from (for example) morning from `january`, `april` or e.i. ..., and in the case that value is `NULL` I want to add `NOW()` or `DATE() +1`, or better is use  `AmendDate >= '2012-01-15' OR AmendDate IS NULL`

Comment: Sorry, I still couldn't get it, would you be able to add the query with select list and where clauses and then tell what you intend to get the output as?

Comment: @Vikdor I want to determine if `Record` is `Amended` or not, maybe replace `NULL` to `DATE +1` is wrong way, sorry for my `Navajo language`

Comment: Since amendDate carries null for records that are not amended, you filtering criteria would be amendDate IS NOT NULL to exclude records that are not amended. Hope I got you right this time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select all records from morning/evening for any of days

```
select *
from Table t
where t.AddDate > '2012-09-03' 
      and t.AddDate < '2012-09-04'
      and DatePart(HOUR, t.AddDate) < 12 -- Morning
      -- and DatePart(HOUR, t.AddDate) > 18 -- Evening
```

For the second part (given that the requirement is not very clear) I think you can use [`Coalesce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function with a `CTE`

```
;WITH FullData(Id, Name, AddDate, AmendDate, Status)
     AS (SELECT t.Id,
                t.Name,
                t.AddDate,
                COALESCE(t.AmendDate, '2012-09-04'),
                Status
         FROM   Table t)
SELECT *
FROM   FullData d
WHERE  d.AddDate <= '2012-09-01'
       AND t.AmendDate >= '2012-09-02'
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, you can use the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function on the date to extract the hour and apply your criteria on whether you are interested in the records added in the morning or in the evening.

```
DATEPART(hh, AddDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 12 -- Morning.
```

Second question is not clear :(

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this for the 2. question? I used a parameter because it is easier to show:

```
  DECLARE @AddDate datetime

    SELECT *
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE 
    AddDate <= @AddDate 
    and AmendDate >= ISNULL(AmendDate,DATEADD(day, 1, @AddDate))
```